# Problem using antlr4 to parse XML tag & attributes

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a simplified antlr4 XML grammar to parse this example:

```
<root>
  <field a="1">
    random text
  </field>
</root>
```

The grammar is:

```
grammar TestKo;    
root        : '<root>' WS* field* WS* '</root>' ;
field       : '<field' attr* '>' chardata* '</field>' ;     // fails
attr        : TEXT '=' '"' TEXT '"';
chardata    : TEXT | WS ;
WS          : (' '|'\t'|'\r'? '\n')+   -> skip;
TEXT        : ~[<&]+ ;
```

Run with antlr4:

```
$ antlr4 TestKo.g4 && javac -cp /usr/share/java/antlr4-runtime.jar TestKo*java 
$ cat ./test.xml | grun  TestKo root -tree
line 4:2 mismatched input '</field>' expecting '='
(root <root> (field <field (attr  a="1">\n\trandom text\n   </field>)) </root>)
```

What is missing to correctly parse the attribute between `field` and `'>'`?
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Always try to print out the tokens that Antlr recognizes. For your grammar and input, the second token is ' a="1">\r\n    random text\r\n  ', which is far too much. The rule for TEXT is incorrect. You might want to check out [the xml grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/xml) in grammars-v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexer runs to completion before the parser considers any parser rule. Corollary: parser rule evaluation cannot affect/influence lexer rule evaluation. So, the rule

```
TEXT : ~[<&]+ ;
```

will consume `[>="/]`, preventing the corresponding implicit tokens from being seen by the parser. (This is the primary fault with the grammar.)

Explanation: implicit tokens are generated for character strings in the parser. This is the one caveat to the "parser does not affect the lexer" truism. They are internally defined as if placed at the top of the lexer rule list, i.e., by magic, and therefore have the highest single character match priority.

The `TEXT` rule can match multiple character strings and, for those strings, has a higher absolute match priority: where multiple lexer rules can match a given input, the rule with the longest match length wins; if the length is the same, the first listed rule wins.

For various practical reasons -- clarity & maintainability -- best to not rely on implicit tokens.

Advice: parsing XML is *not* simple. Distinguishing `random text` from tags, as the current grammar attempts, will be problematic. Given the tags provide clear guard characters -- `<` and `>` -- using the Antlr `mode` capability to cleanly segregate the structured intra-tag vocabulary from that of `random text` will make the grammar much easier to design and maintain.

BTW, `-> skip` does exactly what it says: no token will be produced. So, the parser rule

```
   chardata : TEXT | WS ;
```

will never see a `WS` token.

If you are new to Antlr, the [TDAR](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/) is well worth the read.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I will try to make all tokens explicits for better control of the match priority. And indeed I will need more reading to understand all this and the use of `mode`.

Answer (score 1):

The time I examine the problem and prepare an answer, you have already your answer ...

Negative tokens are difficult to manage, they can consume the rest of the file. With your grammar renamed Question and your data :

```
$ grun Question root -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:5='<root>',<'<root>'>,1:0]
[@1,9:14='<field',<'<field'>,2:2]
[@2,15:40=' a="1">\n    random text\n  ',<TEXT>,2:8]
[@3,41:48='</field>',<'</field>'>,4:2]
[@4,50:56='</root>',<'</root>'>,5:0]
[@5,58:57='<EOF>',<EOF>,6:0]
line 4:2 mismatched input '</field>' expecting '='
```

It doesn't find the = because it has been consumed in token @2 by the first `TEXT` rule of `attr`. Try this :

```
grammar Question;

root        : '<root>' WS* field* WS* '</root>' ;
field       : '<field' attr* '>' chardata* '</field>' ; 
attr        : TEXT '=' STRING ;
chardata    : TEXT | WS ;
STRING      : '"' .*? '"' ;
WS          : (' '|'\t'|'\r'? '\n')+   -> skip;
TEXT        : ~[=<>&]+ ;
```

Execution :

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"
$ alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ a4 Question.g4 
$ javac Question*.java
$ grun Question root -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:5='<root>',<'<root>'>,1:0]
[@1,9:14='<field',<'<field'>,2:2]
[@2,15:16=' a',<TEXT>,2:8]
[@3,17:17='=',<'='>,2:10]
[@4,18:20='"1"',<STRING>,2:11]
[@5,21:21='>',<'>'>,2:14]
[@6,22:40='\n    random text\n  ',<TEXT>,2:15]
[@7,41:48='</field>',<'</field>'>,4:2]
[@8,50:56='</root>',<'</root>'>,5:0]
[@9,58:57='<EOF>',<EOF>,6:0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and advice. In the future I will use `grun -tokens` to investigate and avoid negative tokens when possible.